# What is the equivalent of `never` TypeScript type in Flow?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, flowtype, flow-typed

What is the equivalent of `never` TypeScript type in Flow?

I am working on a project which uses flow for type checking. There I have to define a throwing function. In Typescript we can use never type for function which do not return. I want to do the same with flow but didn’t found anything in the documentation.

I have a condition for invalid types.

```
if(type == 'a' || type == 'b'){
  throw new Error();
}
return type;
```

the function which contains this code has a type which does not include "a" and "b". The above code works. But when i move the if condition in a function it does not work.

```
function throwIfInvalidType(type) {
  if(type == 'a' || type == 'b'){
     throw new Error();
  }
}
```

And then use the function as below it does not work.

```
throwIfInvalidType(type)
return type;
```

https://flow.org/try/#0FAFwngDgpgBAbgQwDYEsAmAVSsC8MDkAxvqNjCgHaKqbYDOMe+C+MAPgQEYmnQzJJwfPNXRY+HSqNrQ6wAGYBXCoRAoA9hRggAFgCd1AdxTyAkhQBqydAAohUAJQBvYDHLy7ZHExbsO9xiZuZ1c3bX0jGAooQxgAUT0DPRsHUIBfYAyFZVUNLQBzKBArJEUoOhSALnhrGVgXNyQimABbMHFcAhYAblDdA2MzS1qbNo7Utz0ixT0tMexerKUVNU0YQuLkMroARiqamg6YBpgmkFb27GqBAJ98XrcTUcvhby7WNg5516D8ELDwgMojF4ol1MkJjAMpNprMLh1FkA

Comment: Why does there need to be one? They are different type systems.

Comment: I am working on a project which uses flow for type checking. There I have to define a throwing function. In Typescript we can use `never` type for function which do not return. I want to do the same with flow but didn’t found anything in the documentation.

Comment: If I was you, I'd [edit] your question to ask that question, because the current one sounds very much an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/xy-problem/info)

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent. Can't you use `void` in both cases ?

Comment: Hi @Tom. Can you check the updated question. Using void does not work.

Comment: Doesn't work *how*? Do you have a playground to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: @caTS I have added link to playground

Comment: Flow's `empty` type is like Typescript's `never`, but I don't think that either apply given the code example you posted, since the return type is dependent on the condition.

Comment: Do you have any solution then?